# deal with multiple arrays being sent to jquery from php?

Tags: php, jquery

This is kind of an odd question, but i'll try to explain it as possible. I have this PHP script which fetches data from MySQL. It gets the userID, Username, Email for each user and puts it in an array:

```
phpoutput = Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => John [lastname] => sena )
Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => human [lastname] => man )
```

and so on for as many records as there are. The problem is that i want to send this data to jQuery in order to manipulate it with jquery. I know how to send and get data with jQuery, but how can i deal with multiple arrays?

Note : I have already used `json_encode()` to encode the arrays.

Comment: @nrabinowitz thanks for editing the question much better now ... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you'd put all of your user records into one large array, then send that array to jQuery as JSON:

```
$array = array(
    array( "id" => "id1", "name" => "John", "lastname" => "Sena"),
    // etc
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

In jQuery, you'll receive the array, and can loop through the user objects:

```
$.get('users.php', function(data) {
    var user;
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        user = data[x];
        console.log(user.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery parseJSON method.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
```

alert( obj.name === "John" );

you can console.log obj to make sure its working if you get annoyed with alerts like me.

Comment: i'll take a look into that ... thanks for your help , sure i'll mark it as my answer if it was .. :)